# React Routing doesnt render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried to learn React and now wanted make a Route but it seems like it doesnt render Overview.
Iam thankful for any help.

```
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Overview from "./pages/Overview";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Sidebar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/overview" components={Overview} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const Overview = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Please Render!!</div>
    </>
  )
};

export default Overview;
```

Comment: getting any console errors?

Comment: Are you rendering the App component at you ReactDOM.render ?

Comment: how are you acessing the route?? copy typing the url link in the bar it self? In homePage does the app render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have type error, you write components instead of component.
Change this

```
<Route path="/overview" components={Overview} />
```

to this

```
<Route path="/overview" component={Overview} />
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Route` accepts `component` as param and not `components`. See [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component)

Your code should be -

```
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Overview from "./pages/Overview";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Sidebar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/overview" component={Overview} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

export default App;

Answer (score 0):

Add `exact` attribute as following:
`<Route path="/overview" exact components={Overview} />`

Comment: already tried that but doesnt seem to change anything...

Answer (score 0):

You must switch **components** to **component**. Just take out the s.